# Laravel search Json column for numbers between two values

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I have a `viewers` JSON column in the `products` table that hold a similar value example:

```
[{"at": "2021-06-21T18:58:39", "age": 30, "country_iso_code": "US"}, {"at": "2021-06-18T11:13:13", "age": 20, "country_iso_code": "PH"}, {"at": "2021-06-25T23:57:12", "age": 45, "country_iso_code": "ET"}, {"at": "2021-06-27T17:01:14", "age": 18, "country_iso_code": "DZ"}
```

So, I'm trying to get rows that contain numbers between two JSON age property values, for example, age between **20-30**.

I have tried to use the eloquent method `WhereJsonContains` but it does only works with the exact number values (as far as I know):

```
$query->orWhereJsonContains('viewers', [
    'age' => 20
]);
```

this code will basically return the following query:

```
select * from `products` where (json_contains(`viewers`, '{\"age\":\"20\"}'))
```

Is there a way I can handle this to use the between? maybe a regex solution

Comment: Is it an option for you to add multiple clauses, e.g, iterate through `[20...30]` and adding `orWhereJsonContains(... 'age' => $i)`?

Comment: It is dangerous holding an age anywhere in a database, It may be right when you insert it, but tomorrow its more likely to be wrong as right

Comment: @nitrin0 thanks for the suggestion I thought about it but I guess this will generate a lot of queries for example ages between 18...80, I'm looking for a single query solution like a regex.

Comment: @RiggsFolly the business model forces us to do since there is no other solution atm.

Comment: Thats a horrible way of storing data (good if you want to make it almost unusable though) remember if for no other reason, there is a limit to the length on a mysql row and its not as large as you might think. If that column is getting used for many occurances of some activity you will soon run out of space. [See the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html)

Comment: Agree, I think i will create another relational table for the ages, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this.

```
return \App\Models\Product::where("viewers->age","<",30)->where("viewers->age",">",20)->get();
```

**->** point to the object